# What's the proper notation for holding one note of a chord while playing the other notes staccato?

Tags: chords, notation, software, staccato

I want to hold down the `A` key on the piano for 3 beats. During the first of these 3 beats ONLY the `A` key is held, but during the second and third beats, I press the `C` and `E` keys staccato on the beat.

Effectively I want a sound like this:

[image: two-handed version of bass note with two chords]

However, I only want this sound to take place in the bass clef and be played with the left hand. Meanwhile the right hand is playing a melody.

I've tried finding an answer to this but most answers involve slurring the entire chord, where you press and hold the `A`, then press and hold the `C`, then press and hold the `E`. They don't offer a way to lift your fingers from `C` and `E` without lifting your finger from `A`.

What's the proper notation for what I'm trying to accomplish? I'm trying to take a small piece I prototyped on a piano and jot it down with some notation software, but nothing seems capable of producing the sound I want. Whenever I declare that the first note of the chord is a dotted half-note, I'm forbidden from placing additional notes in the measure (understandably - the measure already has 3 full beats)

Comment: If you want staccato, better put a dot under each dyad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OI vopiSeveral posts down, there is an example of correct notation.

[image]

I copied it from that post. One notates the sound as two voices (thus the quarter rest) with a dotted half in one voice and a quarter rest and two quarter notes in the other voice. It's a common notation when the keyboard plays more than one voice in each hand.

Answer (score 8):

This is where using more than one *voice* comes into play.Split the bass clef into two voices one with stems pointing downwards, the others pointing upwards.

It's a common thing to do, when effectively there are two separate things happening simultaneously. So the A note underneath will be for three beats, and its stem facing down, and there's a rest above it for the 1st beat. Then come the two crotchets, with their staccato dots, on beats 2 and 3, and their stems up.

We have a lot of questions about 'how come there's 6 beats in a 3/4 bar', etc., and this is usually why!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question about notation software:

This requires a program that allows for multiple voices. Enter the dotted half-note in one voice, then enter the quarter-rest and two staccato chords as a second voice. The software will understand that the two voices are happening simultaneously and format them as desired.

For example, here are instructions for [doing this in MuseScore](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/voices).

Answer (score -3):

I believe it would look like Image 2 below that I've created.

I use Dorico Software, and to create this I plotted the A note and C/E dyads as quarter notes (Image 1).  After this I went into 'Play Mode', turned on 'Notated Durations' and dragged the A note across the the 2 staccato A/C diads to give me image 2 below.

Hope this helps.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: it really should we written as two distinct voices